# Alterar dados de uma posição especifica no ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Gostaria de saber como consigo alterar dados de uma certa posição do ListView.

Aqui carrego do banco de dados para o ListView:

```
public void carregarEmails(Cliente cliente) {
    ArrayList<Email> listaView = dao.pegarResultListaEmail(cliente);
    listaEmail.setAdapter(new ClienteCadEmailBaseAdapter(getActivity(), listaView));
}
```

Codigo que recupero os dados da linha selecionada:

```
private void informacaoSelecionadaEmail(View v) {
    listaEmail = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lstEmails);
    listaEmail.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object o = listaEmail.getItemAtPosition(position);
            objEmail = (Email) o;
            posicaoEmail = position;
            edtEmail.setText(objEmail.getEmail());
        }
    });
}
```

Agora para pegar o alterado no EditText e mandar para a linha novamente que não tenho noção de como fazer.

Comment: Seja bem-vido ao SOpt. Seria legal adicionar o código de suas tentativas para que possamos te ajudar melhor =]

Comment: Ola, muito obrigado, então eu não tenho noção de como alterar, consigo recuperar pelo getItemAtPosition, porém para retornar o valor alterado para a posição eu não tenho idéia de como faz, já pesquisei algo que poderia me ajudar porém acredito estar procurando errado

Comment: Então coloque o seu código atual que iremos te ajudar

Comment: adicionei os codigos de captura do banco e captura do ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *ListView* é uma representação visual dos dados provenientes de uma *fonte de dados*.
Os dados são convertidos em *Views* usando um *Adapter*

Assim, para alterar qualquer dado/valor mostrado pela *ListView*, é necessário alterar esse valor na *fonte de dados* e informar o *Adapter* dessa alteração, usando o método [adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).

Comment: Olá ramaral, se eu entendi após a alteração eu uso o metodo novityDataSetChanged(), li algumas coisas sobre porém não consegui entender, esse metodo serve para persistir os dados  dentro do adapter?

Comment: Vi agora a adição à pergunta. Se você está a usar um BD deveria usar um *CursorAdapter*.  Se quiser continuar a usar o BaseAdapter terá de fazer a alteração no `ArrayList<Email> listaView` e no BD e depois chamar `notifyDataSetChange()`. O *notifyDataSetChange* não persiste nada, apenas informa o *adapter* para que ele actualize a *ListView*.